# How do I list all AWS IAM actions required to perform a Terraform apply?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam

I have about 30 terraform files which have Infra code for aws. AWS resource action operations are required to terraform apply in this files.

I want to find all EC2 operations used in these files like "DescribeInstances", "TerminateInstance"...etc. similarly for other aws resources.

The idea here is to granularize the policy in AWS by finding all AWS resource used in this file and action performed.

How do I list all AWS IAM actions required to perform a Terraform apply?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/61208002/2291321 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/51277207/2291321.

Comment: Thank you @ydaetskcoR   . Yes, tlooks like what i am looking. Will try the policymaker. Thanks for quick response :-)

Comment: I downloaded the tool from https://github.com/scottwinkler/terraform-policymaker/tree/master/policymaker   but the compiling instructions arent clear in git repo. i have go lang installed on windows. Which file i need to supply for compiling.

Comment: I downloaded the tool from https://github.com/scottwinkler/terraform-policymaker/tree/master/policymaker   but the compiling instructions arent clear in git repo. i have go lang installed on windows. Which file i need to supply for compiling. I issued following commad to build the policy maker ... c:\ go build .\main.go . is main.go correct file ?.  but the main.exe opens mouse settings window ...strange. how to build this . Kindly guide here ..  https://github.com/scottwinkler

Comment: i could generate .\terraform-policymaker.exe by just issuing go build cmd under terraform-policymaker . how do supply the parameters . can i give terraform file name directly ??

Comment: I hope I haven't misinterpreted your intent. I wasn't sure if you wanted to list IAM actions granted by your modules or IAM actions required to terraform apply. I assumed terraform apply.

Comment: Hi @AlainO'Dea. Thanks for responding back. Let me rephrase again the query. I am new to terraform. I have about 30 TF files. I need to go through this terraform and identify all actions done on various AWS resources. For eg: there could be 3 operations on EC2 intances describeinstacnes, describevoumes & createinstances. The idea here is to granularize policy which is be given EC2 *. I am looking fr tool which scans this 30 files and give an output of all actions performed instead of manually looking through the file. Hope this clarifies. Not sure if anything out there. ?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you need a tool that determines the least IAM privileges required for your AWS Provider for Terraform.

This tool looks suitable:
https://github.com/scottwinkler/terraform-policymaker

To run it you need to:

1. build it:

   ```
   go build
   ```
2. execute it with a path to the folder where you run terraform apply:

   ```
   ./terraform-policymaker -path=/path/to/where/you/terraform/apply/
   ```

It should output a list of all IAM actions required to execute your plan.

Comment: i did manage to setup terraform-policymaker. after compiling with Go Lang i got the terrafrom-policymaker .exe.  as output. post this supplied the path to the folder where my terraform files exist which needs to be analysed for constructing policy. The output results in aws_policy.json file in terraform-policymaker folder. But this file with have only  follwoing policy.  anything i am missing here . thanks @alain. Here is the policy.        {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
   {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [],
    "Resource": "*"
   }
  ]
 }

Comment: That policy grants no Actions, so it will grant no access. That suggests that your Terraform plan does not create any resources or is in an unsupported format. Are you using Terraform 0.12.x? The tool might not work for earlier Terraform versions.

Comment: Thank you @Alain . Will check. Appreciate your inputs and follow up. Will drop in my findings if am able to get this working with tool