# terraform infrastructure runs locally , building and deploying it on aws codepipeline gives error

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-codepipeline

I have created my aws infrastructure using terraform . the infrastructure includes creating elastic beanstalk apps , application load balancer , s3 , dynamodb , vpc-subnets and vpc-endpoints.

the aws infrastructure runs locally using the terraform commands as shown below:

```
terraform init
terraform plan -var-file="terraform.tfvars"
terraform apply -auto-approve -var-file="terraform.tfvars"
```

The terraform.tfvars contains the variables like region , instance type , access key etc .

I want to automate the build and deploy process of this terraform infrastructure using the aws codepipeline .
How can I achieve this task ? What steps to follow ? Where to save the terraform.tfvars file ? What roles to specify in the specific codebuild role . What about the manual process of auto-approve ?

**MY APPROACH** :The entire process of codecommit/github , codebuild , codedeploy ie (codepipeline) is carried out through aws console , I started with github as source , it is working (the github repo includes my terraform code for building aws infrastructure) then for codebuild , I need to specify the env variables and the buildspec.yml file , this is the problem , Iocally I had a terraform.tfvars to do the job but here I need to do it in the buildspec.yml file .

**QUESTIONS** :I am unaware how to specify my terraform.tfvars credentials in the buildspec.yml file and what env variables to specify? I also know we need to specify roles in the codebuild project but how to effectively specify them ? How to also Store the Terraform state in s3 ?

Comment: What error do you get? How have you configured your pipeline?

Comment: I have specified my approach ? I am stuck when I need to specify buildspec.yml file and env variables for configuring the codebuild project , also I am unaware how to specify roles for codebuild ?

Comment: I was following below mentioned tutorial but as it involves creating aws security services whereas I need to create elastic beanstalk applications and many other things , got stuck while following there steps.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-use-ci-cd-deploy-configure-aws-security-services-terraform/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**- How can I achieve this task ?**

Use CodeCommit to store your Terraform Code, CodeBuild to run terraform plan, terraform apply, etc and CodePipeline to connect CodeCommit with CodeBuild.

**What steps to follow ?**

There are many tutorials on the internet. Check this as an example:
https://medium.com/faun/terraform-deployments-with-aws-codepipeline-342074248843

**Where to save the terraform.tfvars file ?**

Ideally, you should create one `terraform.tfvars` for development environment, like `terraform.tfvars.dev`, and another one for production environment, like `terraform.tfvars.prod`. And in your CodeBuild environment, choose the file using environment variables.

**What roles to specify in the specific CodeBuild role ?**

Your CodeBuild role needs to have the permissions to create, list, delete and update resources. Basically, in one service, it's almost everything.

**What about the manual process of auto-approve ?**

Usually, you use `terraform plan` in one CodeBuild environment to show what are the changes in your environment, and after a manual approval, you execute `terraform apply -auto-approve` in another CodeBuild environment. Check the tutorial above, it shows how to create this.

Comment: There are many tutorials on the internet. Check this as an example: https://medium.com/faun/terraform-deployments-with-aws-codepipeline-342074248843       

given tutorial shows how to build ci/cd pipeline using terraform code , what I want to do is I have aws infrastructure locally running using terraform commands , so i want to build a pipeline using aws code pipeline which will perform the commands terraform init ,terraform plan and terraform apply by itself , building and deploying the aws terraform infrastructure will be done by codepipeline itself .

Comment: The entire process of codecommit/github , codebuild , codedeploy ie (codepipeline) is carried out through aws console , I started with github as source , it is working (the github repo includes my terraform code for building aws infrastructure) then for codebuild , I need to specify the env variables and the buildspec.yml file , this is the problem , Iocally I had a terraform.tfvars to do the job but here I need to do it in the buildspec.yml file , I am unaware how to do so ? I also know we need to specify roles in the codebuild project but how to effectively specify them ?

Comment: You don't need to put your variables inside buildspec.yml. Just put them in a file and dynamic change the name of the file as I said in my response. But, if you still want to put them in the buildspec.yml, you can use Terraform variables as environment variables just exporting it with TF_VAR_ prefix.

There is no easy way to specify what permissions your terraform would use. Check this link below where it shows some suggestions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51273227/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-determine-the-minimum-aws-permissions-necessary

Comment: Thanks @Raul .I am passing the terraform variables as environmental variables using the TF_VAR_prefix but am getting this error :

Error: Error parsing /codebuild/output/src588537846/src/main.tf: At 2:13: Unknown token: 2:13 IDENT var.region

Comment: if I want to put variables in a file and in use that file in my buildspec.yml to perform `terraform plan` and `terraform apply` then how can i do that ??( ps- my file is already created , i need a way to use that file to perform the automation of terraform commands in buildspec.yml file) .

Comment: Hi @aditmodi, you can use `--var-file` to specify which file you want to use. Check this link here: https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/apply.html#var-file-foo

Comment: ` Error: Error parsing /codebuild/output/src588537846/src/main.tf: At 2:13: Unknown token: 2:13 IDENT var.region` facing this issue ??? @Raul Barreto

Comment: It's an error inside your main.tf. By the error description, I think you're using a variable var.region that is not declared in your variables file.

Comment: `Error refreshing state: AllAccessDisabled: All access to this object has been disabled
    status code: 403, request id:xxx , host id:xxx ` , solved above error but stuck on this one.

Comment: Specified Roles , Specified Secret Keys using environmental variables , specified two buildspec.yml files ,for plan and apply. everything works , What to do to improve security?